# Embedding script into React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, embed

I am pretty new to react and was given the following code to embed in one of my components, its essentially an online menu, but I replaced the given URLS with the "#" but will be placing in the correct URL's.

```
<div>
    <script id="frame-script" src="#"></script>
    <script>
        var getParams = function (url) {
            var params = {};
            var parser = document.createElement('a');
            parser.href = url;
            var query = parser.search.substring(1);
            var vars = query.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                var pair = vars[i].split('=');
                if(pair.length > 2) {
                    params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] + '=' + pair[2]);
                }
                else {
                    params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
                }
            }
            return params;
        };
        var baseURL = "#“;
        var params = getParams(window.location.href);
        if(params['path']){
            console.log(params);
            var newSrc = baseURL + params['path'];
            document.getElementById('menu').src = newSrc;
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to go around doing this? I don't mind doing my research and figuring this out on my own, more so just looking to get pointed in the correct direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In React you should avoid using html script tags. What you really want to do is to convert this code snippet on a React way to handle it. You must understand that React handles this kind of problems using states, which are a React component's life cycle methods. You can read more about this on the official documentation [clicking here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

It would look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const [myState, saveMyState] = React.useState(() => null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const url = window.location.href;
    //do your thing with the url here
    // but keep in mind you should not append elements to the html
    // actually you must save the url on a state
    saveMyState(url);
  }, []);

  return (
    <a href={myState}>This is called JSX</a>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
      var getParams = function (url) {
        var params = {};
        var parser = document.createElement('a');
        parser.href = url;
        var query = parser.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split('=');
            if(pair.length > 2) {
                params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] + '=' + pair[2]);
            }
            else {
                params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
            }
        }
        return params;
      };
      var baseURL = "#“;
      var params = getParams(window.location.href);
      if(params['path']){
        console.log(params);
        var newSrc = baseURL + params['path'];
        document.getElementById('menu').src = newSrc;
      }
    `
  }}
/>
```